# Get the current URL but remove the ? and text after this

Tags: php

I've got a fairly trivial question but I'm not sure what the wording is to find a solution in google.

Currently I am using this to get my url...

```
<?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>
```

But the problem is that it is including this **?orderby=newest**

My question how can I get the URL but exclude the `?`, and any text that appears after the question mark?

So if the URL looks like this.

```
www.example.com?orderby=oldest
```

Then the returned URL looks like this...

```
www.example.com
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try doing [`parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

It results in:

```
Array
(
    [path] => www.example.com
    [query] => orderby=oldest
)
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/LmSFGlqa)

Comment: This seem's ideal but how do I put the [path] in a variable? Thanks

Comment: @Joshc just save the results of `parse_url` to a var and use it! ^_^

Comment: Sweet - like this...
`$http = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$url = $http[path];`

Comment: Just realised I can use this... `$url[path];` from this `$url = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);` Thank you!

Comment: @Joshc no problem ^_^. and do `$url["path"]` or else your will have some PHP warnings there.

Answer (score 1):

```
$exploded_url = explode("?", $url);
$url = $exploded_url[0];
```

Explode results in:

```
Array (
   [0] => http://www.example.com
   [1] => x=y&b=z
)
```

Comment: Thanks this did also work :-) just used the above instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) on your input string and cherry-pick the result array for the parts you need.